# Can I use static routing to allow me to use my public IP from my LAN?

Tags: router

I would like to be able to use the same hostname to connect to my computer from my phone whether I'm at home or away.  Currently I have to maintain duplicate entries for remote desktop, for instance.

My router doesn't seem to have a NAT loopback option.  I have two routers in fact, a cable modem which goes straight to my main router which does wireless.  I can add to the static routing tables on each.  Can I use this to loopback the public IP or do I need different routers?

EDIT: I have a Motorola Droid Razr.  The modem router is a Comcast business gateway and the wireless router is a Linksys E2000 with stock firmware.

Comment: It depends on the phone, What phone are you using?

Comment: Razr.  Why does that make a difference?

Comment: What about the router you are using? is it a stock firmware or somthing like dd-wrt?

Comment: Do you have anything on your network other than the router that can act as a DNS server?  The idea being that you have the hostname resolve to the internal address when in your network, and resolve to the external address when outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the same problem you are having by running my own local DNS server that recurses to OpenDNS for non-local domains, and creating zones with local DNS A and PTR records that resolve my external hostname to the LAN IP of that host.

You don't really want to use your "public IP" from your LAN, but rather you want to use the same DNS hostname.

I believe you could add a static route on your system to route your external IP with netmask 255.255.255.255 to the IP of your local system.  However, that IP is going to be your default gateway and I believe the two would conflict.  In essence, it might happen that all your Internet facing traffic ends up going to the IP of that local system.